# c# - Binary search algorithm random generated array items not working

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, random

I have implemented binary search algorithm in a console window application in C#. I am generating random values to the array and sorting them using `Random()`  and `Array.Sort()` functions respectively.

**The Problem** - No matter what ***Key***(item to be searched in the array) I give, the program is returning ***Key not found*** when the array items are generated using `Random` function

This does not happen if I enter the array elements manually using `Console.ReadLine()`.

TLDR: Binary Search algorithm works fine when array items are entered manually, but ***does not work*** when array items are generated using `Random` function.

Can anyone point out what is the mistake I am doing?

***My code - Random Generated array items.***

```
namespace BSA
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new int[10];

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
        }

        Array.Sort(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\n", i);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number to be searched in the array.");

            var searchItem = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var foundPos = Search(arr, searchItem);

            if (foundPos > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key {0} found at position {1}", searchItem, foundPos);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key {0} not found", searchItem);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int Search(int[] arr, int item)
    {
        var min = 0;
        var N = arr.Length;
        var max = N - 1;
        int basicOperations = 0;

        basicOperations++;
        do
        {
            var mid = (min + max)/2;

            if (arr[mid] == item)
                return mid;

            if (item < arr[mid])
                max = mid - 1; 
            else
                min = mid + 1;

            basicOperations++;
        } while (min <= max);

        return basicOperations;
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing any silly mistake or I am committing a blunder in the above code. Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search code works fine as far as I can see. However when you list the contents of the random array, you should write `arr[i]` rather than `i` to see what's in the array so you can pick a search value in it. Alternatively, pass `arr[x]` as the search item. It should return `x`.

Comment: I must admit, I didn't see it either until I debugged it!

Comment: Yeah, I did not pay much attention to that either. I was breaking my head over this and now I am pleased to know the answer.

Comment: Hi @John D. Can I ask you one more doubt? I have edited the above code to calculate the basic operations of the algorithm. I have added increments at the beginning and at the end of the algorithm and returning the value of basicOperations. How can I display the value of basicOperations in the output? Where should I add `Console.WriteLine("Basic Operations {0}", basicOperations);` line in the above code?

Comment: Try passing in a variable `basicOps` as an `out` parameter.
        int numOps;
        int searchPos = IntArrayBinarySearch(arr, arr[5], out basicOps);
        Console.WriteLine("Found at {0} num ops={1}", searchPos, basicOps);

Comment: Thanks a lot @John D that's wonderful! Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works correctly. You're just not looking for the right keys. The function that prints the values generated into the array prints the *loop counter* instead:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\n", i);
        }
```

You need to change it to:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\n", arr[i]);
        }
```

This will show you the values actually generated.

Comment: Thank you @CollBots for pointing out the mistake :) Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Comment too short for this so added answer to show how to set `basicOperations` and still return search position. You declare `basicOperations` as an `out` parameter which means the method can change it so the caller can see it when method returns.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ... ... ...
    int basicOperations;
    int searchPos = IntArrayBinarySearch(arr, arr[5], out basicOperations);
    Console.WriteLine("Found at {0} basic ops={1}", searchPos, basicOperations);
}

public static int IntArrayBinarySearch(int[] data, int item, out int basicOperations)
{
    var min = 0;
    var N = data.Length;
    var max = N - 1;
    basicOperations = 0;

    basicOperations++;
```

and at bottom, you don't need to return `out` parameters, just return -1 to indicate failure as you did before

```
    return -1;
```